# segfault in an unexpected line

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I need to understand why this code produces a segfault at line 15

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void IncrementStringNum(char *str){
    size_t len = 0;

    //checking if the string is valid while also counting the length
    for(size_t i = 0 ; str[i] ; i++ , len ++){
        if(str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9'){
            return;
        }
    }

    //increments the last character if it is less than '9'
    if(str[len - 1] < '9'){
        str[len - 1] ++; // the segfault happens here
    }
}

int main(){
    char *test = "000";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++){
        IncrementStringNum(test);
        printf("%s" , test);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

although thers is no out of bound access or access whatsoever

this is a function that increments a string formated number I needed it for an excercise on code wars I expected it to print strings form 001 till 009 but instead i get a segfault for no reason at line 15

Comment: Literal strings like `"000"` are not supposed to be modified. The compiler tend to put them in read-only memory. Attempting to modify a literal string will lead to *undefined behavior*. That's why it's recommended to use `const char *` type for such strings. If you want to modify the string you need to use an array: `char test[] = "000";`

Comment: On a different note, please use [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) to make sure a character is a digit.